# How do you test for the existence of an active XMLHttpRequest object before aborting a prior $.ajax() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, abort

If I call the `$.ajax()` method and store the XMLHttpRequest into a variable, `vXMLHttpRequest`, what is the correct way to check for the existence of a prior XMLHttpRequest before calling `abort` on it?

```
var vXMLHttpRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

**I'm assuming this is the way to kill the request only if there is an active prior XMLHttpRequest**:

```
if(vXMLHttpRequest)
{
  vXMLHttpRequest.abort();
}
```

Is that right or is there a better syntax? For example:

```
if(vXMLHttpRequest!=null)
{
  vXMLHttpRequest.abort();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first will work, however you can also check the readyState property of the request: if it is 4, it has already completed, so no need to abort.

Answer (score 1):

your right this is valid

```
if(vXMLHttpRequest)
{
  vXMLHttpRequest.abort();
}
```